# unit testing extension function and mocking the other methods of the class

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I am writing an extension function adding some retry capabilities to `AmazonKinesis.putRecords`. In my extension method i do some logic and some calls to the original `putRecords` method:

```
fun AmazonKinesis.putRecordsWithRetry(records: List<PutRecordsRequestEntry>, streamName: String) {
    //...
    val putRecordResult = this.putRecords(PutRecordsRequest().withStreamName(streamName).withRecords(records))
   //...
}
```

From a unit test point of view I am finding it hard to see how I should mock the call to `this.putRecords`

I am using `com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2.*`

```
val successfulRequest = PutRecordsResultEntry().withErrorCode(null);

class KinesisExtensionTest : StringSpec({
    val testRecords = ArrayList<PutRecordsRequestEntry>()
    testRecords.add(PutRecordsRequestEntry().withPartitionKey("iAmABunny").withData(ByteBuffer.wrap("aaa".toByteArray()))
    )

    val kinesis = mock<AmazonKinesis>{
        on { putRecordsWithRetry(testRecords, "/dev/null") }.thenCallRealMethod()
        on { putRecords(any()) }.thenReturn(PutRecordsResult().withRecords(listOf(successfulRequest, successfulRequest)))
    }


    "can write a record" {
        kinesis.putRecordsWithRetry(testRecords, "/dev/null")
        verify(kinesis).putRecord(any())
    }
})
```

The `putRecordResult` is always null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension function `AmazonKinesis.putRecordsWithRetry` will be compiled to a static function under the hood, and Mockito [doesn't support static method mocking yet](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1013).

Therefore Mockito may not know the stubbing information at the verification step and thus the default `null` value is produced.